# Parameters before '?' in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like this:

```
/gallery/page.php?id=object
```

And I want to redirect this page to another page.

Using mod_rewrite, how can I redirect this URL?

I Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=object$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^gallery/page.php/?$ http://www.mysite.com/gallery/page.php?id=new [R=301,L,NE]
```

But this doesn't work fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you want to redirect this url?

Comment: is new page static or dinamic???

Comment: I have edited the original post with new information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=object(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(gallery/page\.php)$ /$1?id=new [R=301,L,NC]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tested this but doesn't work fine. I have edited the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Is this placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` OR `DOCUMENT_ROOT/gallery/.htaccess` ?

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess

Comment: Does `DOCUMENT_ROOT/gallery/.htaccess` exist?

Comment: No, this path doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok please be quick in your responses. What URL did you enter in your browser that didn't redirect?

Comment: www.mydomain.com/gallery/page.php?id=object

Comment: Make sure to place my edited rule as first rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: I have exactly the rules in that i have put in the original post

Comment: Make this rule as your **first rule**

Comment: There is no reason why it wouldn't work. Try in a different browser to avoid 301 caching.

Comment: Ok, now works. Seems that the problem was with the test server. Thanks a lot for your help!